# Java eliminar algunas propiedades en el ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, response

Estoy usando Java con Spring MVC y MyBatis para conectarme a la base de datos. Tengo una tabla cuenta y para algunas consultas necesito todos los campos, pero para otras necesito solo algunas propiedades.

Por ejemplo para mostrar la información básica de la cuenta luego de hacer la consulta con MyBatis algunos campos que no especifico, son retornados como `null`, `false` o incluso `0`. Inicialmente éste era mi ResponseBody:

```
{
  "accountName": "pagos.com",
  "country": "CO",
  "commercialName": "pagaTu",
  "city": "Chiquinquirá",
  "location": null,
  "secureName": null,
  "description": null,
  "document": "1101097231",
  "localOperation": false,
  "address": null,
  "acceptInternationalTransactions": false,
  "balance": 0
}
```

Entonces utilicé la siguiente anotación para evitar los campos con valores nulos:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Account implements Serializable {...}
```

Actualmente mi ResponseBody elimina los nulos así:

```
{
  "accountName": "pagos.com",
  "country": "CO",
  "commercialName": "pagaTu",
  "city": "Chiquinquirá",
  "document": "1101097231",
  "localOperation": false,      
  "acceptInternationalTransactions": false,
  "balance": 0
}
```

Pero como tampoco necesito en la consulta los últimos 3 campos, estos son retornados `false` y `0`. Una alternativa es crear un Modelo solo con los campos que necesito. Pero antes quiero saber si existe otra solución, tal vez removiendo esos campos mientras se genera el ResponseBody.

La respuesta esperada es:

```
{
  "accountName": "pagos.com",
  "country": "CO",
  "commercialName": "pagaTu",
  "city": "Chiquinquirá",
  "document": "1101097231"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar crear un DTO, puedes dejar de utilizar los tipos de datos primitivos en tus entidades y utilizar los wrappers en su lugar:

```
public class Account {
    //los otros campos...
    private Boolean localOperation; //Boolean en lugar de boolean
    private Boolean acceptInternationalTransactions;
    private Double balance; //te recomendaría BigDecimal en lugar de Double
    //resto de la clase...
}
```

De esta manera, los valores por defecto de estos campos ya no serán `false` ni `0` sino `null` puesto que son objetos. Si te preocupa el "overhead" en memoria de este cambio, te diré que la verdad no es muy grande a menos que trabajes con grandes cantidades de datos almacenados en memoria (me imagino 100k de estos elementos en memoria al mismo tiempo, por lo menos).

Answer (score 2):

Lo más cómodo si estás seguro que esos campos nunca van a navegar es usar @JsonIgnore sobre el getter que no quieres que sea serializado.

A partir de la versión 2.6 de Jackson se puede usar com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty sobre la propiedad que se desea no serializar.

Por ejemplo:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
```

private String propertyXXX;

La documentación javadoc indica sobre este tipo de acceso:

```
/**
 * Access setting that means that the property may only be written (set)
 * for deserialization,
 * but will not be read (get) on serialization, that is, the value of the  property
 * is not included in serialization.
 */
  WRITE_ONLY
```